# Trichotomy question with null relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ is a nonempty set. The relation defined on A is the null set. $\emptyset$ would not have trichotomy since the elements of the set are not related in any way,correct?

Comment: Depends on the set $A$. If $A$ is a singleton, then it is indeed the case that for every $a,b\in A$, either $aRb$ or $bRa$ or $a=b$. So in that case, the empty relation *is* trichotomic.

Comment: [ignore my previous comment I totally misunderstood]

Answer (score 0):

For all x,y in the empty set, x < y, y < x AND x = y.  In addition, if P(x,y) is any property, then P(x,y).